# requestAnimationFrame when using mouse cordinates to make animation

Tags: javascript, canvas

animation function that will be called using requestAnimationFrame(animate)
but in the animate function i call is_inside and when that happends i get an error in is_inside function when i want to get wx and wy  : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
Any idea how to fix this ? Thank you

```
function animate(event){ 
    targetX = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left; 
    targetY = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top; 
    canvas.style.cursor = "pointer";
    if(clicked!=true){
        if(is_inside(pointx,pointy)){
            move();
        }else{
            canvas.style.cursor = "auto";
            moveLeft();
        }
    }   
}

function is_inside(x,y){

    var wx = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    var wy = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;
    var distance = Math.sqrt((wx-x-400)*(wx-x-400) + (wy-y-300)*(wy-y-300));
    if(distance < 35){
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}


canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', animate, false);
```

Comment: `is_inside` doesn't have a way to reach the event object. Either pass it or pass the mouse positions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you won't have access to any event in requested frame callback. You need to store mouse position from event on mousemove and just use it in `animate` function

```
var mousePosition = {x: 0, y: 0};

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', event => {
    mousePosition.x = event.clientX;
    mousePosition.y = event.clientY;
}, false);
```

then instead of `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` use `mousePosition.x` and `mousePosition.y` respectively